# Swift 3 Photo Library

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I just updated to Swift 3 and I tried to run this code

```
    @IBAction func selectProfilePhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I run this code, It just crash!